# pyqtgraph - how to change the y axis label?

Tags: plot, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, yaxis

I create a desktop application using pyqt5 and use pyqtgraph to draw a graph
Here is my code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
self.graphWidget.showAxis('left')
self.graphWidget.setYRange(0,100)
.....
   set data code
.....
```

The graph was drawn correctly, and the left axis display value range from 0 to 100. But when I change the Y range to a different range:

```
self.graphWidget.setYRange(0,200)
```

But the left axis still displays a value range from 0 to 100 (I expect that it will display from 0 to 200 after the changing value was performed)
What's wrong with my code? I have searched for the answer but did not find it. Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: How/when are you calling `setYRange()`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I have 2 buttons: Start and Reset. I init the graphWidget variable in __init__ function. When the Start button was pressed, I will call to setYRange and start to draw the graph. When the Reset Button was pressed, I will call setYRange again and redraw other graph with new data set

Comment: As said, please provide a MRE.